# Почему Exсeption на сервере?

Tags: ajax, asp.net

В контроллере на сервере есть метод в который подаем строку `http://localhost:61641/Company/GetSearchValue?search=ле` и должны найти компании которые ее содержат и вернуть `json`, но получаем `exсeption`.

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The entity or complex type
>   'CRM.Models.Company' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities
>   query.

**Почему?**

```
public JsonResult GetSearchValue(string search)
    {
        List<Company> allsearch = db.Companies.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search)).Select(x => new Company
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name}).ToList();

        return new JsonResult { Data = allsearch, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

Comment: Вот тут поищите ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916080/the-entity-or-complex-type-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query.

Comment: Просто уберите `Select`.

Comment: Да, без select все ок и json в ответе прилетает. А как все таки с нужными полями ответ отправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение путем добавления AsEnumerable() после Where

```
List<Company> allsearch = db.Companies.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search)).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Company
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
List<Company> allsearch= db.Companies.Where(n => n.Name.Contains(search)).ToList();
```

Comment: Так работает, но отдает в ответе все свойства объекта. 
Я выше написал как подтянуть только Id и Name
    
        'List<Company> allsearch = db.Companies.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search)).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Company
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name
        }).ToList();'